# Java - Find number of children in a LinkedBinaryTree

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes, children

I'm working on a method in my LinkedBinaryTree class that can count the number of children in a tree. My code is below, but when I run it in my driver, I get into a bit of an infinite loop.

```
public int children(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) {
    int children = 0;
    if(node.getLeft() != null){
        children = 1 + children(node);
    }
    else if(node.getRight() != null){
        children = children + 1 + children(node);

    }
    return children;
}
```

Particularly, it's this line that causes the StackOverflow error, and I can't move beyond it:

```
children = 1 + children(node);
```

Anyone have any idea how to help me correct my code? Anything I'm overlooking with my logic? Appreciate the help.

Comment: You're passing the same node in your recursive calls, it should be `node.getLeft()` and `node.getRight()` respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass node-> left or node->right while recursively calling the method. Corrected code:

```
public int children(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) {
int children = 0;
if(node.getLeft() != null){
    children = 1 + children(node.getLeft());
}
else if(node.getRight() != null){
    children = children + 1 + children(node.getRight());

}
return children;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public int children(BinaryTreeNode<T> node) {
    if (node == null)
        return 0;
    return 1 + children(node.left()) + children(node.right());
}
```